# How to use the ".ScrollTo" list view method in C#/Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to figure out how to use the ScrollTo method that is available with list views. I believe I have the last two arguments correct, but am not quite sure if I have the first argument correct.

Here is the xaml with my list view for my view...

```
         <ListView
            x:Name="MyList"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="4"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="8"
            ItemsSource="{Binding History}"
            ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"

            RowHeight="60">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Margin="8">
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding MessageTitle}"
                                FontAttributes="Bold" />
                            <Label 
                                Text="{Binding MessageContents}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

And here is part of the code behind for that view where I am trying to use .ScrollTo

```
 private void ScrollToBottomClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List.ScrollTo(MyList.ItemsSource, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
    }
```

Here is the ItemSource, which is an observable collection in my view model

```
public ObservableCollection<HistoryMessage> History
    {
        get
        {
            return History;
        }
        set
        {
            History = value;
        }
    }
```

When the ScrollToBottom button is clicked I am wanting the list view display to jump the the most recent item added.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

In my code behind I have the following method, in my case is void because I only call when I load all the list

```
    public void ScrollDown(HistoryMessage historyMessage)
    {
        List.ScrollTo(historyMessage, ScrollToPosition.End, false);
    }
```

So, when all I get all the list I call this method

```
    ScrollDown(History.LastOrDefault());
```

If you have a button and you want me to show you the closest item of the list, you should make a query to your API to see if there is any element added and later call this method and sent the lastOrDefault element.

If what you want is the first element you need change List.ScrollTo(historyMessage, ScrollToPosition.End, false) to List.ScrollTo(historyMessage, ScrollToPosition.Start, false) and sent de first element in your observable collection